# VBA file operations

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro in VBA to make excel file in specific location, but the filename have to be provided from userform.
So far here's my code:

```
Dim wbname, wbsheet, wblocat As String    
Dim wbghkv As Double    

wbname = devserv.wbnamebox 'name of workbbok from userform    
wbsheet = devserv.wbsheetbox 'name of worksheet from userform    
wbghkv = devserv.ghkvbox 'value of gerate hkv from userform    
wblocat = "T:\nf\usefullstuff\excel" 'location of file folder

Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="wblocat \ wbname"    
Workbooks(wbname).Activate    
Worksheets.Add    
Worksheets.Add.Name = wbsheet
```

But I get an error at `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs`.....
Before I tried to use `chdir` function before the `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs` but the file was saved in mydocuments .
Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to save as the literal string `"wblocat \ wbname"`.

Instead, try `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=wblocat & "\" & wbname`.

As an aside, `Dim wbname, wbsheet, wblocat As String` declares `wbname` and `wbsheet` as `Variant`. If you want them to be `String`, you'll need to use `Dim wbname As String, wbsheet As String, wblocat As String`.